# installing mod_perl with centos and plesk

Tags: plesk, mod-perl, centos5

I'm trying to install mod_perl on Centos 5.5 with Plesk.  Does this already come with mod_perl? I'm not showing anything in the $ENV{MOD_PERL} variable.

I tried installing it via cpan (install mod_perl2) with this:

**Please provide a full path to 'apxs' executable**

which I don't know. So I skip it and then I am asked:

**Please provide the location of the Apache directory:**

Searched though I have, I can't seem to find it. No apache folder with ap_release.h.

Where would I find this or is there a better way to install it via plesk?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: Please try: a2enmod perl or enable mod_perl in apache's config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get mod_perl2 installed by:

```
>> yum install perl-devel
>> cpan
>> install YAML
>> install mod_perl2
```

Then, I configured it thanks to this: http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=httpd&f=9

I added a new `<Directory>` for my web site in case there would be a conflict with plesk.

`/cgi-bin`  runs regular perl scripts

`/mod-perl`  runs my scripts using mod_perl2... the $ENV{MOD_PERL} variable does exist here!

@oleg - thanks for your help, a2enmod perl does not work in CentOS

The *Perl Support* check box in Plesk doesn't seem to have any effect what-so-ever.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this already come with mod_perl?

Yes. Check any domain's hosting settings.

also you can check:

```
rpm -qa | grep perl
```

and I'm definitely recommend you use Plesk on Centos 6, because most things will be easier.

Comment: I'm getting the latest version of mod_perl installed, but when I run "httpd -l" it is not listed. My $ENV{MOD_PERL} variable is empty. (I forgot I updated my server so I am actually using Centos 6.) How would I enable mod_perl if it listed in your command?